# Dependent node reference

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have three content types

Company

Store

Offer

A Company has many Stores , A Company have many Offers. An Offer belong to many Stores.

Store has a node reference field for Company
Offer have two node reference fields, one for Company and one for Store.

I want that, when creating Offer node, when user select the company, the relevant Stores dropdown populates with stores from that specific company.

Best Regards,
Rafiq Ahmed

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Almost no one here is going to write something from scratch for you - you need to show some attempt at solving the problem yourself. What have you tried, what have you looked into, and why didn't those options work for you?

Comment: Store content type have a node reference field of company id, Offer content type have two node references company id and store id. On Add Offer node I have two dropdrowns , one for company and one for store, I want when the user select the Company the respective stores of that company appear in the node reference field of stores. I tried hierarchical select and conditional field module but no success.

Comment: take a look at this(https://www.drupal.org/node/2310165) you are going to need to write some custom code to do what you want I think, if you can't an existing module to do what you need.